# Android set alarmManager to trigger daily

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In my app, I need to start a service at 2:00pm daily. Right now I wrote the code to trigger the alarm once, this code is ran every time I open the app:

```
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DownloadReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmMgr.cancel(pIntent);

    Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,refreshhour);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,refreshmin);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    // if the scheduler date is passed, move scheduler time to tomorrow
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > cal.getTimeInMillis()) {        
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
       }


    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23) {
        alarmMgr.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);    
        }
    else{
         alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pIntent);
        }
```

**Q1.** I used `setAndAllowWhileIdle()` for sdk above 23 in case the device is in [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html) mode. I cannot find any option in this function that I can set the alarm to repeat every day.

**Q2.** I also have questions about `setInexactRepeating()` , normally it is set to repeat every day by setting the parameter `INTERVAL_DAY` , but in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), it says

> As of API 19, all repeating alarms will be inexact and subject to
>   batching with other alarms regardless of their stated repeat interval.

Does this mean `INTERVAL_DAY` does not work anymore, so how can I set the alarm daily without rerunning this function and reset alarmManager?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code will solve your problem-

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

boolean flag = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                            new Intent("totime.action.string"),
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

if(!flag)
{
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 14);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Intent intent = new Intent("totime.action.string");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Data_Graph.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),(24*60*60*1000), pendingIntent);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but as said in my post, isn't that AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY not working after api 19?

Comment: @ywj7931 you can accept the answer if you find answer helpful.

Comment: I am confused, INTERVAL_DAY should be the same as 24*60*60*1000 according to the source code:  public static final long INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 15 * 60 * 1000; and INTERVAL_DAY = 96*INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES, which is your number, so my question is if this parameter is working after api 19

Comment: Thanks for relying, what about setAndAllowWhileIdle(), I cannot use setRepeating after api 23, because if the device is in doze mode, it will not trigger setRepeating alarm