# How to send notifications depending on date

Tags: android

I have an calendar app where the info is downloaded online and there is a recyclerView of events and I want to notify the user when there is a calendar event for today, and notify with the event name or names. I have done some googling but haven't been able to figure this out.

In my MainActivity.java this is the method I created as a test from a page online

```
private void addNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_check);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert, Click Me!");
    mBuilder.setContentText("Hi, This is Android Notification Detail!");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    // Add as notification
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
}
```

But when I call this method nothing is happening, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the channel of the notification

I have a different solution, try this one (I checked it on my phone)

calling the function:

```
showSmallNotification(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "title","message");
```

**Function code**

```
 private void showSmallNotification( int icon, String title, String message){
        String CHANNEL_ID = "Channel_01";
        String CHANNEL_NAME = "Notification";

        // I removed one of the semi-colons in the next line of code
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

        inboxStyle.addLine(message);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            // I would suggest that you use IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT instead of IMPORTANCE_HIGH
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.enableVibration(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.enableLights(true);

            //channel.canShowBadge();
            // Did you mean to set the property to enable Show Badge?
            channel.setShowBadge(true);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

       Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, mainIntent, 0);


        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), CHANNEL_ID)
                .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 100})
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setLights(Color.BLUE, 3000, 3000)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                .setContentText(message);

        // Don't forget to set the ChannelID!!
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            notificationBuilder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(CHANNEL_ID, 1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

**Edit**

In order to check if there are any events every day you will need to use AlarmManager as from it's name you can schedule an event every day
You can see a solution (or at least it will give a direction) once you did that I think the next step would be to send the intent to a service which will check if there are any events available in current day. If there are any just show the notification/s

[alarm manager link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40545123/12546733)

Comment: where does this go?

Comment: I changes it to this, and still nothing happens

Comment: I'm sorry about that, I think now it will work correctly

Comment: Perfect! Do you have any idea how I would sent these automatically checking if there is an event for today?